# Mongodb + php5-fpm not working

Tags: php, mongodb

i installed mongodb extension for `php5-fpm`.
Output from php -m:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

php --ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

,
I get loaded modules:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => zlib
    [7] => bcmath
    [8] => bz2
    [9] => calendar
    [10] => ctype
    [11] => dba
    [12] => dom
    [13] => hash
    [14] => fileinfo
    [15] => filter
    [16] => ftp
    [17] => gettext
    [18] => SPL
    [19] => iconv
    [20] => mbstring
    [21] => session
    [22] => posix
    [23] => Reflection
    [24] => standard
    [25] => shmop
    [26] => SimpleXML
    [27] => soap
    [28] => sockets
    [29] => Phar
    [30] => exif
    [31] => sysvmsg
    [32] => sysvsem
    [33] => sysvshm
    [34] => tokenizer
    [35] => wddx
    [36] => xml
    [37] => xmlreader
    [38] => xmlwriter
    [39] => zip
    [40] => cgi-fcgi
    [41] => PDO
    [42] => curl
    [43] => gd
    [44] => json
    [45] => mysql
    [46] => mysqli
    [47] => pdo_mysql
    [48] => readline
    [49] => mhash
    [50] => Zend OPcache
)
```

I dont know what is wrong. I search all stackoverflow for solution, but i cant find anything that help me solve this problem.
I hope i get a solution here.